# 'Depends' object has no attribute 'query'

Tags: python, authentication, oauth, fastapi

I´m trying to do the OAuth Authentication in FASTAPI, and i alreday got connected to my database

```
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

I want to compare that the username entered matches the one that is registered in the database

```
def get_user(nombre_usuario: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)): 
    try:
        usuario_db = db.query(models.Usuarios).filter(models.Usuarios.nombre_usuario == nombre_usuario).first()
        if not usuario_db:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Usuario no encontrado")
        
        return usuario_db

    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        return {"error": "Error al consultar en la base de datos"}
```

```
def authenticate_user(username: str, password: str):
    user = get_user(username)
    if not user:
        return False
    if not verify_password(password, user.password):
        return False
    return user
```

Witch this works perfectly if i put it in a route

But i am not sure to include the getdb function if i want to call the getuser function with def authenticate_user...

I already tried tu change this line; but id dosen´t work
user = get_user(username, Depends(get_db))

Comment: I don't really know FastAPI, but [this page](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) shows `Depends()` being used in type annotations, not the default value of a parameter.

Comment: `Depends` only gets resolved from a route, you can't use it as a function yourself. So if the `Depends` part in `get_user` needs to get resolved, it needs to be be put in a route (since it's the controller function that depends on the db being injected). If you want to call `get_user` yourself, just call `get_db` first yourself. It's a regular function.

Answer (score 1):

You are using depends in a wrong place

```py
def get_user(nombre_usuario: str, db: Session): 
    try:
        usuario_db = db.query(models.Usuarios).filter(models.Usuarios.nombre_usuario == nombre_usuario).first()
        if not usuario_db:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Usuario no encontrado")
        
        return usuario_db

    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        return {"error": "Error al consultar en la base de datos"}

@app.post("/auth")
def authenticate_user(username: str, password: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    user = get_user(username, db)
    if not user:
        return False
    if not verify_password(password, user.password):
        return False
    return user
```

Comment: It didnt work, had the same problem

Comment: do you get some errors?